# Stray Characters in included file

Tags: php, codeigniter

Take a look at this image

[image: http://cl.ly/3L1v3k1R3M1q2F433q3O]

The source code in the link is jumbled. Additionally, saving the file as html yields some strange characters above the doctype, seen here

[image: http://cl.ly/2F2y2Z353M2B2m051Y0b]

The php header source code begins in the following way:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  xml:lang="en">
<head>
....
```

Additionally, the header file is included at the top of another file using

`<?php include ('includes/public_header.php'); ?>`

...which is also the first line in the file. So, my question is, **why are there stray characters before the doctype and in what ways can I solve this issue?**

A little more information: This site (downtowngreensboro.net) is using CodeIgniter and the header and other documents are UTF-8 encoded.

---

Upon further exploration, it appears this issue is limited to CodeIgniter. The blog section (Wordpress) shows clean source code.

Comment: Are you sure that there's no trailing whitespace at the end of any of your included PHP files? Also, what editor are you using? Can you save as UTF-8 *without BOM*?

Comment: I checked the files...no trailing whitespace. I use Coda for Mac...and yes, I've saved the files in UTF-8 without BOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out an auto-loaded helper file in CodeIgniter was causing the issue. At the end of the file was a closing php tag, which CodeIgniter warns against. Removing it fixed the problem entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The "strange characters" seem to be null bytes: piping the source code to `hd`, I see this:

```
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
000000e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 3c  |...............<|
000000f0  21 44 4f 43 54 59 50 45  20 68 74 6d 6c 20 50 55  |!DOCTYPE html PU|
00000100  42 4c 49 43 20 22 2d 2f  2f 57 33 43 2f 2f 44 54  |BLIC "-//W3C//DT|
00000110  44 20 58 48 54 4d 4c 20  31 2e 30 20 54 72 61 6e  |D XHTML 1.0 Tran|
00000120  73 69 74 69 6f 6e 61 6c  2f 2f 45 4e 22 20 22 68  |sitional//EN" "h|
```

That's a total of 239 null bytes before the `<!DOCTYPE` tag.  (The hexdump omits some of them, marked by the `*`.)  I'm not sure where they're coming from, though — you should look at your PHP source files in a hex editor to see if they're there.

Comment: I did a hex dump of the public header file and am getting 
`$ hexdump public_header.php --> 0000000 3c 21 44 4f 43...` so it doesn't seem to be a problem at that point. I've also loaded the header into a page by itself http://downtowngreensboro.net/testing/check_it ... still problematic.